# TSLint not excluding 'node_modules' since updating to Vue 2.7?

Tags: npm, webpack

Does anyone know why I am seeing the following in my console when I use WebpackStream to build my files?

```
ERROR in /my-project/node_modules/vue/types/jsx.d.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /my-project/node_modules/vue/types/jsx.d.ts(39,20)
      TS1005: ';' expected.
```

From what I am seeing it is linting `node_modules`?

This is my `package.json`

```
{
    "name": "MyProject",
    "version": "1.1.0",
    "description": "",
    "author": "",
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": ""
    },
    "license": "ISC",
    "main": "NA",
    "scripts": {
        "clean": "gulp clean",
        "watch": "gulp",
        "predevelop": "npm run format",
        "develop": "gulp build --env=develop && gulp build:my-project --env=develop",
        "prebuild": "npm run format",
        "build": "NODE_ENV=production gulp build --env=production && gulp build:my-project --env=production",
        "lint": "gulp lint",
        "format": "prettier --write 'assets/js/refactor-modules/**/*.{js,ts}'",
        "test": "jest --no-cache --forceExit",
        "test:coverage": "jest --coverage --no-cache --forceExit",
        "test:watch": "jest --no-cache --watchAll",
        "precommit": "npm run lint && npm run test"
    },
    "browserslist": [
        "> 5%",
        "last 4 versions",
        "IE 10"
    ],
    "devDependencies": {
        "@ronilaukkarinen/gulp-stylelint": "^14.1.2",
        "@types/jest": "^22.2.3",
        "@types/lodash-es": "^4.17.1",
        "@types/urijs": "^1.15.35",
        "@vue/test-utils": "^1.3.6",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.16",
        "axios": "^0.17.1",
        "axios-mock-adapter": "^1.13.1",
        "babel": "^6.23.0",
        "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
        "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
        "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
        "colors": "^1.4.0",
        "depcheck": "^1.4.3",
        "fancy-log": "^1.3.2",
        "gulp": "^4.0.2",
        "gulp-autoprefixer": "^4.0.0",
        "gulp-babel": "^7.0.0",
        "gulp-cli": "^1.4.0",
        "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
        "gulp-csso": "^3.0.0",
        "gulp-filter": "^5.0.1",
        "gulp-group-css-media-queries": "^1.2.2",
        "gulp-imagemin": "^7.1.0",
        "gulp-load-plugins": "^1.5.0",
        "gulp-noop": "^1.0.1",
        "gulp-plumber": "^1.2.1",
        "gulp-rename": "^2.0.0",
        "gulp-replace": "^0.6.1",
        "gulp-sass": "^5.1.0",
        "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.6.5",
        "gulp-tap": "^1.0.1",
        "gulp-tslint": "^8.1.4",
        "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.2",
        "husky": "^0.14.3",
        "imagemin-gifsicle": "^7.0.0",
        "imagemin-jpegtran": "^7.0.0",
        "imagemin-optipng": "^8.0.0",
        "imagemin-svgo": "^10.0.1",
        "intersection-observer": "^0.5.0",
        "jest": "^24.9.0",
        "jest-localstorage-mock": "^2.4.18",
        "lodash": "^4.17.5",
        "lodash-es": "^4.17.11",
        "merge-stream": "^2.0.0",
        "moxios": "^0.4.0",
        "node-emoji": "^1.11.0",
        "regenerator-runtime": "^0.11.1",
        "sass": "^1.53.0",
        "sass-loader": "^7.3.1",
        "sass-mq": "^6.0.0",
        "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
        "stylelint-config-standard-scss": "^11.1.0",
        "ts-jest": "^24.3.0",
        "uuid": "^3.2.1",
        "vue": "^2.7.14",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.7.15",
        "vuex": "^3.6.2"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@types/jquery": "^3.3.33",
        "@types/lodash": "^4.14.87",
        "@types/node": "^8.0.53",
        "@types/nouislider": "^9.0.4",
        "@types/ua-parser-js": "^0.7.36",
        "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
        "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
        "bootstrap-vue": "^2.0.0-rc.27",
        "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
        "del": "^3.0.0",
        "event-stream": "3.3.4",
        "maska": "^1.5.0",
        "minimist": "^1.2.5",
        "nouislider": "^11.1.0",
        "numeral": "^2.0.6",
        "optimize-js-plugin": "^0.0.4",
        "path": "^0.12.7",
        "postcss-sass": "^0.5.0",
        "prettier": "^1.7.4",
        "through2": "^2.0.3",
        "ts-loader": "^3.1.1",
        "tslint": "^5.8.0",
        "tslint-config-airbnb": "^5.3.0",
        "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.6.0",
        "typescript": "^3.9.9",
        "ua-parser-js": "^1.0.2",
        "urijs": "^1.19.1",
        "vue-awesome-countdown": "^1.1.4",
        "vue-barcode": "^1.3.0",
        "vue-demi": "^0.14.6",
        "vue-recaptcha": "^2.0.3",
        "webpack": "^3.8.1",
        "webpack-stream": "^4.0.0"
    },
    "homepage": ""
}
```

This is my `webpack.config.js`

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const optimizeJsPlugin = require('optimize-js-plugin');
const path = require('path');
const config = require('./config');

const { srcDir, distDir, jsFiles } = config;

const webpackConfig = {
    target: 'node',
    devtool: 'source-map',

    entry: {
        /**
         * `main.refactor`, `es2015.polyfills` & `intersectionObserver.polyfill`
         * are referenced elsewhere using [name] to specify the output file name
         */
        'main.refactor': path.resolve(`${srcDir}${jsFiles().refactor.main}`),
        'es2015.polyfills': path.resolve(`${srcDir}${jsFiles().refactor.polyfills.es2015}`),
        'intersectionObserver.polyfill': path.resolve(`${srcDir}${jsFiles().refactor.polyfills.intersectionObserver}`)
    },

    output: {
        // output each of the above bundles using the entry name as the value for [name].
        path: path.resolve(`${distDir}`),
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        chunkFilename: '[name].[chunkhash].chunk.bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/_ui/responsive/common/js/'
    },

    plugins: [
        /**
         * expose `NODE_ENV` to webpack, so we can use `process.env.NODE_ENV`
         * inside this file for any environment checks
         */
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
            }
        })
    ],

    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                // options defined in `.babelrc`
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules\/(?!(vue-awesome-countdown)\/).*/,
            },
            {
                test: /\.ts|\.tsx$/,
                // options defined in `.babelrc` & `tsconfig.json` respectively
                use: ['babel-loader', 'ts-loader'],
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss?$/,
                loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'scss-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.css?$/,
                loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
            }
        ]
    },

    node: {
        fs: 'empty'
    },

    resolve: {
        // allow specified files to be imported without extensions
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.vue', '.json'],
        /**
         * by default, Vue.js includes the `runtime-only` build when included
         * as an import. We require the full `runtime + compiler` build in order
         * to compile external templates, so we use the `alias` feature
         * to map the `Vue` import to the full compiler build
         */
        alias: {
            'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
        }
    }
};

// push production-only plugins
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    webpackConfig.plugins.push(
        // minimise all JavaScript output
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compress: {
                unused: true,
                dead_code: true, // big one – strip code that will never execute
                warnings: false,
                drop_debugger: true,
                conditionals: true,
                evaluate: true,
                sequences: true,
                booleans: true,
                screw_ie8: true
            },
            output: {
                comments: false
            }
        }),
        new optimizeJsPlugin({
            sourceMap: false
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.AggressiveMergingPlugin(),
        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
            minimize: true
        })
    )
};

module.exports =  webpackConfig;
```

This is my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        /**
         * Basic Options
         */
        "target": "es5",                     /* Specify ECMAScript target version: es5 aligns with Vue's browser support */
        "module": "commonjs",                /* Specify module code generation: 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd' or 'es2015'. */
        "moduleResolution": "node",          /* Determine how modules get resolved: 'Node' for `Node.js` style resolution, or 'Classic' */
        "lib": ["dom", "es2015", "es2017"],  /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation:  */
        "allowJs": true,                     /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */
        "checkJs": true,                     /* Report errors in .js files. */
        "sourceMap": true,                   /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
        "removeComments": true,              /* Do not emit comments to output. */
        "downlevelIteration": true,          /* Provide full support for iterables in 'for-of', spread, and destructuring when targeting 'ES5' or 'ES3'. */
        "isolatedModules": false,            /* Transpile each file as a separate module (similar to 'ts.transpileModule'). */

        /**
         * Strict Type-Checking Options
         */
        "strict": true,                      /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
        "noImplicitAny": false,               /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
        "strictNullChecks": true,            /* Enable strict null checks. */
        "noImplicitThis": true,              /* Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type. */

        /**
         * Additional Checks
         */
        "noUnusedLocals": true,              /* Report errors on unused locals. */
        "noUnusedParameters": true,          /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
        "noImplicitReturns": true,           /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,  /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */
        "experimentalDecorators": true,      /* Required by vue-class-component, which enables us to write Vue compenents using class-based syntax */

        /**
         * Module Resolution Options
         */
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": false /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
    },
    "include": [
        "assets/js/refactor-modules/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "gulp-tasks/*",
        ".stylelintrc"
    ]
}
```

And before anyone says anything, it is a f*cking mess, I'm trying to unpick it all so I can start an updated pipeline :/

Only thing to note is I am stuck on Webpack 3 at the moment...

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated

Tried excluding node_modules site-wide in `webpack.config.js` ad `tsconfig.json`